# How do I protect a file from direct download?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a webshop im developing, and some of the products need to be downloadable files (e-books, images, mp3 etc.). I have the files stored in a subfolder in my project and just a reference to them in my DB.

I dont want anyone with a direct file link to be able to download them, i want to control this myself. The download should only be available through my shop - that is, my customer area where the user can see all the e-products they have purchased.

How do i protect the files on my disk from being downloaded except by my code?

Comment: Is it correct to assume that only some files will be accessible to a given user, or are users qualified to download all materials once a certain condition is met? If it's the latter, you could make use of the `<location />` element in your Web.config to restrict access to only authenticated users.

Comment: You could [create your own HTTP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227439(v=vs.100).aspx) that watches a specific directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to prevent the IIS static file handler from serving out the files to a client.

1) Using  section in configuration.  You can use the hiddenSegments element to specify sub-segment paths that will not be served.  Look at %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config for how this section is defined and used to prevent access to bin folder and other directories.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                 <hiddenSegments>
                      <add segment="subdirectoryName" />
                 </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

2) If you're looking for a simpler "poor-mans" way of blocking static file handler from serving out files, you can make the files "hidden" (from a file system attribute perspective).  The static file handler will not serve out hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer: Don't place these files inside your site, place them outside the root of your site.

You can configure IIS to not serve requests to this folder with request filtering:

I'm assuming these paths are not paths you wanted to serve?